# Null id is getting pass to flow in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

I have created 2 component. from Component1 I'm calling Component2 to open flow in Modal which is working as expected. But when I'm passing Id from Component1 to Component2 it is showing as blank in flow's input variable. I tried various things from different articles to resolve this issue but facing same issue again. Any help would be appreciated!

Component1:

```
<c:LtngCmpUtil_sldsModal aura:id="openFlowModal" closeAction="{!c.closeFlowModal}" >
    <aura:set attribute="header">
        Site Action {!v.siteId}
    </aura:set>    
    <aura:set attribute="content">
        <c:LtngCmpUtil_HOP_SiteToAction siteId="{!v.siteId}"/>
    </aura:set>
    <aura:set attribute="footer">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.closeFlowModal}">Close</button>
    </aura:set>
</c:LtngCmpUtil_sldsModal>
```

Component2:

```
 <aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="siteId" type="String" access="global" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller of component2:

```
    ({
    init : function (component) {
        
        var flow = component.find("flowData");
        var siteId = component.get("v.siteId");
        console.log('Site Id: '+siteId);

        var inputVariables = [
            {
                name    : "recordId",
                type    : "String",
                value   : component.get("v.siteId")
            }
        ];
        console.log('input flow parameters ' + JSON.stringify(inputVariables)); 
        
        flow.startFlow("Site_HOP_Call_to_Action", inputVariables);
    },
})
```

I can see I'm getting value in siteId of component2's .cmp file but it is showing blank in component2's .js file.

Any thoughts, what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [order of initialization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_lifecycle.htm) is what is causing the issue. With a parent and child aura component, the child aura component actually initializes first before siteId has been passed by the parent.

> When the component tree is ready, the init event is fired for all the components, starting from the children component and finishing in the parent component.

If you had a `aura:if` to check that the siteId exists before initializing the child, then it should solve the problem

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.siteId}">
 <aura:set attribute="header">
 ...rest of your componet
</aura:if>
```

Comment: Actually it is passing id to child component and I'm able to see it in .cmp file of child component but in .js file of child component it is some how showing as blank. Not sure why

Comment: it's passing the information once the parent initialize which is after your child has already initialized. In other words, your child js ran before the parent had initialized and passed the variable information - the parent is still passing the variable after that which is why it shows in the child component but not the js.

Comment: ohh okay understood, yep that makes sense. I'll do some modification as per your suggestion. Thanks so much :)